# Use Heroku with register.com

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

I have a free app hosted on Heroku, and a domain on register.com. How can I connect the two? I am OK with using any service or addon, as long as it is free. The only stipulation is that I can not spend ANY money. I also want to be able to have an m subdomain for a mobile site. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions to configure [custom domains](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains).

You just need to install the free `custom_domains` addon.

```
$ heroku addons:add custom_domains
```

Then add the domains

```
$ heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

Then, don't forget to update the DNS settings on your domain provider to point to Heroku IP.